# In the Features module, what does "Recreate" do?

Tags: 7, features

What does it mean to "recreate" a feature? How does this affect the database?  How does it affect the files, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreate allows you to re download the feature, including any changes made to config along with the option to add new config.

Comment: So is "recreate" intended as a way to change the features? To make changes to features, does one recreate the feature, download it, and replace the existing feature module in the file system?

Comment: Yes. That is how it works. Also, features does not remove code from the .module file, so custom code is safe.